# How to split php output in multiple columns?

Tags: php, css

I'm new to php and I've searched for solutions to my problem through all the internet but still cant find a solution for my problem.

I have a php code that looks like this:

```
<?php 
if ($comments_count) {
    for($i=0; $i<$comments_count; $i++) {
        if ($dont_show_email[$i] != '1' && $email != '') { 
            $author[$i] = "<a href=\"mailto:{$email[$i]}\">{$author[$i]
        }
        </a>"; 
    }
    $text[$i] = str_replace(chr(13), '<br />', $text[$i]);
?>
<div>
  <?php print $author[$i]; ?>
  <?php print $time[$i]; ?>
  <?php print htmlspecialchars_decode($text[$i]); ?>
 </div>
```

That displays and output like this:

```
Post 1
Post 2
Post 3
Post 4
```

I have tried almost anythign I found but I couldn't make it work for me. CSS column-count didnt worked also because every post has different height sizes so most posts were cut by the half at the end of one column.

I want to make the output shown like this:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3
Post 1   Post 2   Post 3
Post 4   Post 5   Post 6
```

I need to split the output in columns like that so every post can keep the different height size.

Thank you in advice for your help.

Comment: What is     $comments_count. print_r($comments_count); exit;

Comment: not php related you are looking for a css solution. try `display:inline-block` on posts `div`

Comment: Surely you are talking about a HTML table as the simplest mechanism of achieving that layout

Comment: Try writing the HTML/CSS to get the layout that you want, then use PHP to generate it. As cske mentioned, `inline-block` will probably be the simplest route. You'll probably find this easier than trying to learn HTML, CSS and PHP all at the same time.

Comment: This is starting to look and smell like a ___do it for me question___

Comment: You could have a look at CSS `display: flex`

Comment: @RiggsFolly well, it may look like one but I been trying to make this work and searched for a solution  a long time. I just signed up to stackoverflow to ask because this was beyond my domain.

Comment: Nice @LukeBriggs so simply solution I didn't even thought of it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (HTML borderless table-based) solution:

```
<table style="border: none;">
<?php 
$columns = 3;
for($i=0; $i<$comments_count; $i++) {
    if ($i % $columns == 0) echo "<tr>"; // begin of row
    echo "<td>{$author[$i]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$time[$i]}</td>";
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars_decode($text[$i]) . "</td>";
    if ($i % $columns == ($columns - 1)) echo "</tr>"; // end of row
} ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice solution. This is great and it works fine. But it's not waht solved my problem at all. Changing the display of posts as @LukeBriggs said solved. But thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Update html code

```
<div class="box">
```

Add css

```
.box{float:left; width:31%; margin:3px; padding:5px;}
```

Comment: From the point of view of someone who works on a HTML/CSS layout engine, I'm not much of a fan of `float` being used this way; it's not what it was designed for. `inline-block` with a declared width is much better for this purpose.

Comment: You can do like that too :)

Comment: `Float` affects its siblings and parent in complex ways, which ultimately makes it perform poorly when overused and may result in unexpected flow problems. It was designed to be used to push the occasional image to the side of an article, and have the text flow around it, rather than create entire layouts using floating elements.